# Pass ID to controller on prev or next

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a list of ID

```
IList<string> pageIDList = new List<string>();
```

In my MVC view I have two links

```
<a href="@Url.Action("MyAction", new { id= item.id})"> Previous </a>
<a href="@Url.Action("MyAction", new { id= item.id})"> Next </a>
```

Depending on which page I am, I want to pass the correct ID to MyAction action/controller.

I want to iterate over my pageIDList and get the current ID and if Previous link is clicked, I want to pass the ID which is before the current. If Next link is clicked, I want to pass the id next to the current ID.

Is there a way I can iterate over my pageIDList inside the href link?

I have the following code prepared, but no Idea where to insert it and pass the correct ID to my action.

```
@{int i = 0; }
@foreach (var z in pageIDList)
{
   if (item.id.ToString() == z[i].ToString())
   { 
     id=z[i+1].ToString();
   }
}
```

I really appreciate for any idea/suggestion.

Comment: That foreach loops seems off at first glance.  You are not incrementing the ````i```` variable, so each time you are just comparing the same index.  Why not just use [0] instead?

Comment: Why not just model bind your View with a Model containing Previous/Next properties, when the Action is called, reduce or add to each property accordingly and pass it to the View.

Comment: @JohnPete22 you are right, i missed to increment i, but assume i++ is there, what would be your suggestion?

Comment: @RyanWilson every page has the same properties, depending on the id I will pass, the content will change.

Comment: @MedhanieW. I know. That's why I'm saying to Model bind so that when you call "MyAction" you change those properties on the Model server side and pass it back to the View, populating new { id= item.id}) with Previous/Next  properties of Model. MyAction should be passing the ID back to your controller, and you should be able to modify Previous/Next properties at that point based on the id passed to your Action.

Comment: As far as the ForEach, why is the ````i```` supposed to be there? The only reason I'd think you'd have that is if you wanted to nest a For Loop inside the ForEach to iterate through the ````z```` indexes.

Comment: @RyanWilson Great suggestion! I had to read a little about Model bind and seems fine, but it is displaying the old id in my browser `localhost:52874/MyController/MyAction/originalID?action=next` that my action get at first. How can i update this? When next/prev is clicked the equivalent ID must be displayed in the browser too

Answer (score 2):

If the list of strings is already sorted then you can increment and decrement the index by using the following:

```
pageIDList[pageIDList.IndexOf(item.id.ToString()) + 1]
pageIDList[pageIDList.IndexOf(item.id.ToString()) - 1]
```

So setting id in the href would look like:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("MyAction", new { id = pageIDList[pageIDList.IndexOf(item.id.ToString()) - 1]})"> Previous </a>
<a href="@Url.Action("MyAction", new { id = pageIDList[pageIDList.IndexOf(item.id.ToString()) + 1]})"> Next </a>
```

EDIT:
With element validation it would look like:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("MyAction", new { id= pageIDList.IndexOf(item.id.ToString()) > 1 ?  pageIDList[pageIDList.IndexOf(item.id.ToString()) - 1] : null })"> Previous </a>
<a href="@Url.Action("MyAction", new { id= pageIDList.IndexOf(item.id.ToString()) < pageIDList.Count ?  pageIDList[pageIDList.IndexOf(item.id.ToString()) + 1] : null})"> Next </a>
```

Comment: Great one, but am facing index `was out of range. must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection` error, that was the my reason to write for loop. Any idea please?

Comment: Then your ````pageIDList```` collection doesn't have that index.  If you're on the 0 index, and you use -1 then that is obviously going to throw an error, or if you use +1 and that index doesn't exist then you'll get the error as well.

Comment: After reviewing the comments made by others, I recommend adding the next and prev ids to the model. Leave the logic server side.